# Hibernate SchemaExport from the Commandline

Tags: java, hibernate, schemaexport

I'm new to hibernate and have been attempting to run the SchemaExport hdm2ddl tool from the command line (windows) as:
`java -cp "lib/*" org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport --config=src/hibernate.cfg.xml --create src/hello/Message.hbm.xml`

My directory structure is as follows:

```
- HelloWorld
    - bin
    - lib (all of the required jars - list omitted for brevity)
    - src
        - hello (HelloWorld.java, Message.java & Message.hbm.xml)
        - persistence (HibernateUtil.java)
        - hibernate.cfg.xml
        - log4j.properties
```

Attempting to run the command yields the error below:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [src/hibernate.cfg.xml]
        at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:53)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:163)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.buildStandardServiceRegistry(SchemaExport.java:579)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.main(SchemaExport.java:546)
```

My research so far:

1. The command cannot find the hibernate.cfg.xml file. changing the spelling of the file in the command to a wrong spelling yields the same error.
2. Copied the cfg.xml file into both the classpath (lib) and the HelloWorld directories. The error persisted.

This is basically the example from "Java Persistence with Hibernate" but running it from the command line instead of using ant.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Hibernate looks "**hibernate.cfg.xml**" file in classpath **root folder**. You can try the following:

1. copy "`hibernate.cfg.xml`" file to the current folder (where you run `java ...` command)
2. add current folder ('`.`') to the classpath. (Note: you need to add classpath delimiter char too. It is '`:`' on Linux, and '`;`' on Windows)

So the final command (on Linux) should be:

```
java -cp ".:lib/*" org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport --config=hibernate.cfg.xml --create src/hello/Message.hbm.xml
```